# Google Maps JavaScript API: monitoring clientside geocoding credits/quotas

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are currently developing a new website for our company. In this process, we want to enhance the Google Map functionalities we are offering to our customers.

Currently we are using Google Maps JavaScript API Services for the following functions:

- loading of Google Maps to display our retail stores
- clientside geocoding (customer inserts an individual address and this position is shown on the map)

Until now, we are using the API via the Google standard plan and are getting along with the free credit quotas offered by Google.

However, in the new website, we want to automatically show additional helpful store information to our customers using the Distance Matrix API to show how far the next 5-10 retail stores are from their location (in kilometers and in travel time car&feet in hrs/min). Due to the API documentation and pricing table, this function will of course cause a lot more API credit usage, especially in combination with the geocoding, which we are already using.

To make a decision on which functions and how many of them we can “afford” on a consistent basis, we need to get the figure for the currently used credits. In the API manager for the Google Maps JavaScript API Services we can only see the API-Key figure for “map loads per day”, but not the figure for the usage of the clientside geocoding using the Google Maps JavaScript API. However, the latter one is the more important figure for us for calculating the expected usage of the new functions of the Distance API.

Question: where do we find the geocoding figures? Do we maybe have to create a separate API-Key for the adress search function, so that the clientside geocoding can be tracked separatly? We actually thought this is all handled wit the one API-key we are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

Both client side and server side geocoding requests are calculated against Geocoding API in the Cloud developer console.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#quotas

If you use only client side geocoding, select Geocoding API in your developer console and check the usage graph. If you use both client side and server side geocoding, you can filter usage by API key that you use to initialize Google Maps JavaScript API.

The same thing for distance matrix service. You should check the usage graph for Distance Matrix API in the Cloud developer console.

There is also a feature request in the Google issue tracker to add ability to check usage programmatically:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830575

Feel free to star this feature request to add your vote.